# Access Rails model field from an ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

As we know,if we have a model like this:

```
class TMem < ActiveRecord::Base
   def expense
     return 'OK'
   end 
end
```

The table `t_mems` does't have the field `expense`

But we can access the field in controller:

```
TMem.find(1).expense
```

But if an action return a json:

```
render json:  TMem.find(1)
```

I can't  get the field `expense` from an ajax request.It shows that,the response json doesn't include the field.

So I want to know how to query the model so that I can get this field from an ajax request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override `to_json` in your model with your custom methods

Change your model like

```
class TMem < ActiveRecord::Base
   def expense
     return 'OK'
   end 

   def to_json(options={})
     options[:methods] ||= [:expense]
     super(options)
   end

end
```

Now if you call `to_json`

```
TMem.first.to_json  #=> "{\"t_mem\":{\"id\":1,\"expense\":"OK\"}}"
```

Comment: I find the answer , just `render json: TMem.find(1).to_json(:methods=>:expense)`